# React Redux dealing with large nested tree updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

First of all, I am an absolute newcomer to redux. In our project we have a very **large editable tree table** that is created from a large, **deeply nested tree**. The table contains approximately (x, y) 15x250 = 3700 cells (most of them are not visible until the user expands the entire tree table). I was wondering which way is best for an implementation in react redux.

Additional information: If you edit a value at [0, n] (worst case), all values ​​change and must be re-rendered. On average, n values ​​change per user input.

I struggle with three questions:

1. State structure - is it worth normalizing (and / or making flat) the tree?
2. Status updates - Should the entire tree be updated at once, or is it more sensible to update every single value (possibly with redux batch)?
3. Does that make sense at all or should we do all the calculations on the server side and just render the entire table with a new tree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a Redux maintainer.

[We specifically recommend normalizing complex/nested state if appropriate](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#normalize-complex-nestedrelational-state).  That, in combination with techniques like [passing item IDs to children as props and having them read their own individual values from the store](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#connect-more-components-to-read-data-from-the-store), will help you improve rendering performance in the app.

The second question has multiple potential answers, and I'd need to see some concrete examples of what kinds of update logic you're trying to run.  In general, we recommend [modeling actions as "events", not "setters"](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#model-actions-as-events-not-setters), and minimizing the number of actions that you dispatch.

I'd specifically recommend using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org).  It's our recommended approach for writing Redux logic, and includes [a `createEntityAdapter` API](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter) that can help with managing normalized data in the store.

We just published a brand-new ["Redux Essentials" core docs tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) that teaches "how to use Redux, the right way", using our latest recommended APIs and practices like Redux Toolkit and the React-Redux hooks API.

Finally, you might want to read through the slideshow [High Performance Redux](http://somebody32.github.io/high-performance-redux/), which was written a few years ago, but the basic principles there still apply.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to normalize a state tree is [normalized-reducer](https://github.com/brietsparks/normalized-reducer), which lets you pass in a schema of your relationships, and it gives back the actions and selectors to make changes in a way that is consistent with your model.